# Node.js (Heroku integration with Salesforce): How to get records from Salesforce and display them on a Heroku app using Node.js

Tags: heroku, node.js, continuous-integration, postgres

I have created an Heroku app to be able to retrieve records (**Contracts**) from Salesforce and display them on my Heroku app.
But I am struggling to write the correct request on my node.js code.
Basically when pressing "**Retrieve Contracts**", I would like to get a list of contracts as shown on the pic.

[image]

But in my case, I get an Error anytime I press "**Retrieve Contracts**"
**{"error":"relation "contract" does not exist"}**

[image]

To get the records from Salesforce I'm using "**Express.js**" and "**app.get**" (here is a snippet)

```
    app.get('/getContracts', function(req, res) {

    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function (err, conn, done) {

        // watch for any connect issues
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        conn.query('SELECT Name,Product__c FROM Contract WHERE Product__c != null',
        function(err, result) {
            console.log(result)
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({error: err.message});
            }
            else {
                // Need to display 'Success!'
                res.json(result);
            }
        });
        
    });
});
```

here is the full code:

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var pg = require('pg');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/update', function(req, res) {
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function (err, conn, done) {
        // watch for any connect issues
        if (err) console.log(err);
        conn.query(
            'UPDATE salesforce.Contact SET Phone = $1, HomePhone = $1, MobilePhone = $1 WHERE LOWER(FirstName) = LOWER($2) AND LOWER(LastName) = LOWER($3) AND LOWER(Email) = LOWER($4)',
            [req.body.phone.trim(), req.body.firstName.trim(), req.body.lastName.trim(), req.body.email.trim()],
            function(err, result) {
                if (err != null || result.rowCount == 0) {
                  conn.query('INSERT INTO salesforce.Contact (Phone, MobilePhone, FirstName, LastName, Email) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)',
                  [req.body.phone.trim(), req.body.phone.trim(), req.body.firstName.trim(), req.body.lastName.trim(), req.body.email.trim()],
                  function(err, result) {
                    done();
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(400).json({error: err.message});
                    }
                    else {
                        // this will still cause jquery to display 'Record updated!'
                        // eventhough it was inserted
                        res.json(result);
                    }
                  });
                }
                else {
                    done();
                    res.json(result);
                }
            }
        );
    });
});

app.get('/getContracts', function(req, res) {

    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function (err, conn, done) {

        // watch for any connect issues
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        conn.query('SELECT Name,Product__c FROM Contract WHERE Product__c != null',
        function(err, result) {
            console.log(result)
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({error: err.message});
            }
            else {
                // Need to display 'Success!'
                res.json(result);
            }
        });
        
    });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

index html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CRM AXG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#phoneChangerForm").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var errorMessage = $("#errorMessage");
                var error = $("#error");
                error.hide();

                $("#message").hide();

                var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
                var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var phone = $("#phone").val();

                if (firstName.length == 0 || lastName.length == 0 || email.length == 0 || phone.length == 0) {
                    errorMessage.text("All of the fields are required.");
                    error.show();
                }
                else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: event.target.action,
                        method: event.target.method,
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            firstName: firstName,
                            lastName: lastName,
                            email: email,
                            phone: phone
                        }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#firstName").val("");
                            $("#lastName").val("");
                            $("#email").val("");
                            $("#phone").val("");
                            $("#messageMessage").text("Record updated!");
                            $("#message").show();
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                            errorMessage.text(err.responseJSON.error);
                            error.show();
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#getContractForm").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var errorMessage = $("#errorMessage");
                var error = $("#error");
                error.hide();

                $("#message").hide();


                $.ajax({
                    url: event.target.action,
                    method: event.target.method,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#name").val("");
                        $("#product__c").val("");
                        $("#messageMessage").text("Success!");
                        $("#message").show();
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        errorMessage.text(err.responseJSON.error);
                        error.show();
                    }
                })
                
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Contact Information</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="phoneChangerForm" action="/update" method="post" style="width: 400px">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Contact Information</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="For verification" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="For verification" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="For verification" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="New Phone Number" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div id="message" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span id="messageMessage"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                        <span id="errorMessage"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Contact</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Contract Information</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="getContractForm" action="/getContracts" method="get" style="width: 400px">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Contract List</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div id="message" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span id="messageMessage"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- display retrieve contracts result-->
                    <Table>
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- <jS>data.foreach(d) => <tr>d.name</tr></jS> -->
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>

                    <div id="error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                        <span id="errorMessage"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Retrieve Contracts</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">CRM AXG</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="getContractForm" action="/" method="get" style="width: 400px">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Product List</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contractName">Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contractName" placeholder="For verification" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div id="message" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span id="messageMessage"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                        <span id="errorMessage"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Retrieve Products</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you confirm you're connected to salesforce at this statement -     `pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function (err, conn, done){`

Comment: yes, As the first request "app.post"  works perfectly
if I press "update contact" on the app. Everything is fine. The contact is updated on Salesforce accordingly. But I am not able to retrieve contract information

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the error:
I needed to update my SOQL query

```
conn.query('SELECT Name,Product__c FROM salesforce.Contract WHERE Product__c != null'
```